# How (or where) to see errors when something goes wrong using truffle exec <script>?

Tags: truffle

I want to know how ( or where if logged somewhere) to find errors when running truffle exec . And this because i ran truffle command  and a dependency was missing (i forget a require) and i didn't see any errors.

Answer (score 2):

I find useful to insert a try catch and then console.log the error in order to see what was happening:

```
HelloWorld=artifacts.require("HelloWorld");

module.exports = async (callback) => {

    try {
               //code here 

    } catch(e){
        console.log(e)
    }

}
```